# unity Rotate between min and max distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, hololens

I'm trying to make it possible to drag an object. This object can only rotate so much. (Similair to a door).

Here is the code abit edited that rotates an object which works.
I have 2 vectors for maxrotation and minrotation.

This code will be called whenever the user is dragging the interactible object. (like update but only when dragged)

```
        if (GestureManager.Instance.IsNavigating &&
    HandsManager.Instance.FocusedGameObject == gameObject)
        {
            //speed and navigiation of rotation
            float rotationFactor;
            rotationFactor = ManipulationManager.Instance.ManipulationPosition.y * RotationSensitivity;
            totransform.Rotate(new Vector3(rotationFactor, 0, 0));
        }
```

It would be great if I could use an if statement here. And I tried quite some things but it's still not working.

As stated the code paste here works. The object should be dragable but only up to a certain points.

totransform is the transform that will be rotated

Any ideas would be great and most appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: Hmm, what did you try? You could do a `Debug.Log(rotationFactor);` before the totransform.Rotate and copy the values on your desired max and min positions, then do an `if (withinThatRange) { Rotate }`. Should work! Or rather, check the rotation first.

Comment: btw the "totransform" isn't a typo, right?

Comment: ah sorry I didn't elaborate I'll change it. totransform is the transform of the object that will be transformed.

Comment: If you are working on a door, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129162/open-a-door-front-and-back-in-unity3d-similar-to-amnesia/37133811#37133811).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html). Check the values you're getting then set an if-statement before doing the rotation. This is a sample code for you to find the values you want:

```
if (GestureManager.Instance.IsNavigating &&
    HandsManager.Instance.FocusedGameObject == gameObject)
{
    //speed and navigiation of rotation
    float rotationFactor = ManipulationManager.Instance.ManipulationPosition.y * RotationSensitivity;

    Debug.Log(totransform.eulerAngles);
    if (totransform.eulerAngles.x < 100) {
        totransform.Rotate(new Vector3(rotationFactor, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: So let's say in this instance the minimal rotation of x = -90 and the maximum 0. when debugging I check the value of X in eulerangle which is transformed to a number like 3. Whilst the original x rotation is -80. but only after running the application it changes to 3 when calling eulerangle

Comment: Ah, right... -1 in the inspector is 359 degrees. For positive numbers it makes more sense: http://imgur.com/a/l1qfC hehe.

Comment: Well, the eulers gets you the correct angle, but it's not going to be the same numbers as in the inspector. For instance, -90 degrees counter clockwise is 270 degrees clockwise, which is what you're getting from the eulerangles. Use transform.localEulerAngles.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip I think that puts me in the right direction. For some reason localeulerangles is the same though.

Comment: And I found the problem. Seems the eulerangle has it's own degrees like you said. Guess I have to adapt to that as I cannot find how to get the same value as the inspector. Thanks for bringing me on the right track!

Comment: Nice! Great job! Sorry I couldnt help more

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution that worked for me. First I declare the movement variable (not seen down below, which is 2 in this case). Then I track the distance covered and put a limit on that.

Of course there are some improvements to this code like use movement instead of 2. But because of time constraints I didn't do it.

```
    if (GestureManager.Instance.IsNavigating &&
    HandsManager.Instance.FocusedGameObject == gameObject)
        {

                //here we get the movement direction and set it in movement.
                if (GestureManager.Instance.NavigationPosition.y > 0)
                {
                    movement = 2;
                }
                else if (GestureManager.Instance.NavigationPosition.y < 0)
                {
                    movement = -2;
                }


            //the first part is false if we reach higher then maxdistance and the movement is going up
            //the second part is false if we reach the lower distance and the movement is going down.
            if ((!(distance > maxdistance.x) || movement < 0) && ((!(distance < mindistance.x) || movement > 0)))
                {
                    //here we add the movement to the distance so we know if it gets closer or further
                    distance += movement;
                    //here we rotate
                    totransform.Rotate(new Vector3(movement, 0, 0));
                }
        }
```