# Unity5 - How to limit the rotation of a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player is floating in Space, when it should turn left or right, it spins along the z axis

```
float x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical");

transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
rigidBody.AddForce (transform.up * flySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (Time.deltaTime * -y * rotateSpeed,
    Time.deltaTime* x * rotateSpeed, -Time.deltaTime * -x * rotateSpeed));
```

Comment: This is neither C nor UnityScript - it's C#

Comment: Also the correct tool to look into this would be a debugger (or use `print` debugging) - However you are always rotating around 3 axes, so it's unclear why you'd expect a different result

Comment: I write to C#, but ...,ok i cut z position from my script, but how limited rotation

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html
You're rotating around all three axes at once. If you want to only rotate around a single axis, two of the three euler angles need to be zero

Comment: I think you are asking two different things, in the title you were asking who to limit rotation, like +120 to -120 degrees. But in the next sentence it looks like your problem is the gameobject is rotating in an axis you didn't expdect.

Comment: Он вращает, но мне нужно, если limitet (transform.Position.X> 30) { x = 30} HOW LIMITED  ?

Comment: Hey! I answered [a question like this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277113/unity-rotate-between-min-and-max-distance/42277355#42277355)

Comment: Dear friends I need using Mathf.Clamp but how...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your object to rotate only in on z-axis and assuming you have rigidbody associated to your object, you can freeze the rotation in rigidbody component in inspector by checking in the constraint section on x and y-axis.

By this way, it can only rotate in z-axis

Comment: Dear Friend, my game is about Cosmonaut in space, when I turn to left he rotate but he rotate on 360 grade when I need on 30 grade in Local axes,
Sorry for my english!