# Opening doors in UNITY as in visage or amnesia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, rotation, quaternions

I'm attempting to replicate a comparable door opening style seen in games like Visage or Amnesia. So, if I approach a door and hold the mouse while dragging downwards (towards me), the door will open towards me. Conversely, if I do the opposite, the door will naturally open away from me [An example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4i72qLAusxI&t=96s).

I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129162/open-a-door-front-and-back-in-unity3d-similar-to-amnesia) that accomplishes exactly what I need. However, the issue is that if, for instance, I open the door only halfway and then approach from the other side to close it, it resets back to its initial rotation (0 degrees). [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TxUHopKn6Y)

Thanks for any advice